# Checking time difference, MS Access

Tags: time, ms-access-2003

I have an MS Access Database table that records communication status of values from several meters. The data is logged directly to the table, but I need to make sure that the table is populating. From the sample data you can see that the Comm columns doesn't  read  false or 0, so I want to return a log whenever the difference between now and "Date / Time" is greater than 5 minutes.

```
Date / Time            FCB Comm   BOF Comm      EAF Comm    FGP Comm 
9/6/2011 10:29:10         1       1        1        1   
9/6/2011 10:28:01         1       1        1        1   
9/6/2011 10:27:11         1       1        1        1   
9/6/2011 10:26:20         1       1        1        1       
9/2/2011 08:17:01         1       1        1        1       
9/2/2011 08:16:10         1       1        1        1   
9/2/2011 08:15:02         1       1        1        1       
9/2/2011 08:14:08         1       1        1        1
```

I wanted to know if anyone could tell me if this could like a reasonable query to run?

```
    SELECT Data.[Date / Time], Data.[Ford Chiller Building Comm Okay], 
Data.[Basic Oxygen Furnace Comm Okay], Data.[Electro-Arc Furnace Comm Okay], 
Data.[J-9 Shop Comm Okay], Data.[Ford Glass Plant Comm Okay]
    FROM Data 
    where DateDiff("n",now(), Data.[Date / Time] ) < 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need something running continuously that generates a notification whenever expected data doesn't appear, and there's a couple of approaches you can take to do that.

One is to continuously run a query like the one you have above, checking the most recent date in the table against the value of the now() function.

Another approach is to take the latest date in your table, wait (sleep) for 5 minutes, and then check the table again for any newer entries.  My expectation is that this approach will generate fewer hits on your table.

You could also just check the most recent date every 5 minutes regardless of the previous time checked and see if data hasn't come in.

You need to set up your notification loop first, then you can experiment with different approaches.

---

all you should really need to do is return the number of rows in the table whose timestamp is within 5 minutes of now().  You shouldn't need additional row detail, just is the count 0 or not?

Comment: Your initial idea is part of my plan. I suppose that I should have included that. I plan to run this is a service application that would run every 5 minutes. My idea is that the service would run every 5 minutes to verify that the most recent record has a date within 5 minutes of the current date/time. If this is not true then I will receive an email telling that the data is not updating.